# How can I write a method to intersperse two arrays of different lengths?

Tags: java, arrays

If the first array contained 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and the second contained 6, 7, 8, the resulting array should contain 1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 5, 6. What I have so far seems really long and complicated, and it only works when the two arrays are of equal length.

This is what I have right now

```
public static int[] intersperseC(int[] array1, int[] array2)
{
    int[] resultArray = new int[array1.length + array2.length];
    if (array1.length>array2.length)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<array2.length; i++)
        {
            if (i%2 == 0)
                resultArray[i] = array1[i/2];
            else
                resultArray[i] = array2[i/2];
        }
        for (int i=array2.length; i<resultArray.length; i++)
        {
            resultArray[i] = array1[i - array2.length];
        }
    }
    if (array2.length>array1.length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<array1.length; i++)
        {
            if (i%2 == 0)
                resultArray[i] = array1[i/2];
            else
                resultArray[i] = array2[i/2];
        }
        for (int i=array1.length; i<resultArray.length; i++)
        {
            resultArray[i] = array2[i - array1.length];
        }
    }
    if (array1.length == array2.length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<resultArray.length; i++)
        {
            if (i%2 == 0)
                resultArray[i] = array1[i/2];
            else
                resultArray[i] = array2[i/2];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("I should not be here.");
    }
    return resultArray;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's often a trick you can use with a seperate cursor.....

```
public static int[] intersperseC(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    int[] resultArray = new int[array1.length + array2.length];
    int cursor = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.max(array1.length, array2.length); i++) {
        if (i < array1.length) {
            resultArray[cursor++] = array1[i];
        }
        if (i < array2.length) {
            resultArray[cursor++] = array2[i];
        }
    }
    return resultArray;
}
```